# Acces primarySwatch of ThemeData in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-theme

I'm using two different `ThemeData` classes for switching between dark and light mode. However I am using a color scheme which requires me to access the colors inside the swatch I have defined.

```dart
static const int _greyPrimaryValue = 0xFF1E1E1E;
static const MaterialColor darkSwatch = MaterialColor(
    _greyPrimaryValue,
    <int, Color>{
      0: Color(0xFF000000),
      50: Color(_greyPrimaryValue),
      100: Color(0xFF222222),
      200: Color(0xFF242424),
      300: Color(0xFF272727),
      400: Color(0xFF2C2C2C),
      500: Color(0xFF2E2E2E),
      600: Color(0xFF333333),
      700: Color(0xFF353535),
      800: Color(0xFF383838),
      900: Color(0xFF424242),
    },
  );

get darkTheme => ThemeData(
   primaryColor: darkSwatch.shade50,
   primarySwatch: darkSwatch,
)
```

Is there a way to acces the values in my primarySwatch? I can use `Theme.of(context)` to access different values like `primaryColor`. Is there a way to access the colors I defined inside my swatch instead of assigning them to different keys in ThemeData? Otherwise what's the point of creating a swatch?

**Wanted behaviour**

```dart
Container(
   color: Theme.of(context).primarySwatch.shade100,
)
```

**Current situation**

```dart
bool _isDarkTheme = Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark;

Container(
   color: _isDarkTheme ? lightSwatch.shade100 : darkSwatch.shade100
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Theme.of(context).primaryColor` and `Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary` are of type `Color`.  `primarySwatch` is a `MaterialColor` which inherits from `Color`.  You need to cast your primary color as a `Materialolor` to get the shades of your swatch:

```
((Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary) as MaterialColor).shade900
```